# URL encoded colon (%3A) resolves in 403

Tags: apache, rest, url, mod-rewrite

I'm hosting some rest APIs in an Apache server (a typical xampp package).

When I attack a resource with an http method (whichever: put, post, get...) and the URL contains an encoded colon %3A, the server sometimes replies with a 403 error. It seems to depend on the folder structure of the server. If there's an existing folder and your url attacks a resource that contains %3A in that folder, the server returns 403. When it doesn't contain %3A, it returns 404 like it should.

with a structure like this:

```
htdocs/apis/userContext
htdocs/apis/subscriptions

http://localhost/apis/userContext/users/tel%3A2032342349 Works (returns 404 not found, because users doesn't exist)
http://localhost/apis/userContext/tel%3A2032342349 Doesn't work (returns 403)
http://localhost/subscriptions/tel%3A2032342349 Doesn't work (returns 403)
http://localhost/nonexistingfolder/tel%3A2032342349 works (returns 404, becasue nonexistingfolder doesn't exist)
```

It's quite annoying since a lot of the values that are going to appear in the urls are telURIs and look like this

```
tel:+34678678678
```

so please don't tell me not to use colons there because that's simply impossible. How could I fix this?

Comment: What are your rewrite rules so far?

Comment: I have everything redirected to index.php since I'm using the slim framework to handle all the requests to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find only one valid information about this (from October 2006) - [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk:Short_URL/Archive_1#Colon_issue_with_Very_Short_URLs_on_Windows).

Apparently, this error doesn't appear on Linux, it happens on Windows platforms. According to the source, a short name, followed by colon (:) could be interpreted as a drive name (why is that and why file:// doesn't denote that - I don't know).

I had to solve this issue, but I could set the links myself (don't know if You have the luxury). My solution was to:

- replace colons in URI by a character of choice (I chose the underscore) - `urlencode($uri) → urlencode(strtr($uri, ":", "_"))`
- search for those URIs after applying the same replacement - `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE uri = REPLACE(@@uri, ":", "_")`

Comment: Thank you very much! This seemed to be exactly the problem as when I moved it to a Linux environment the problem disappeared (it was months later so I had even forgotten that I wrote this). Regards!